# php trying to start a local program with the function exec()

Tags: php, cmd, exec

I have a website running on a webserver and i want to start a local program for the users that they have installed on their computer but it doesn't return anything and it doesn't start the program

Here is the following code i use

```
<?php
    $ret = exec('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Exact Software\bin\E5Shell.exe"', $output, $error);

    // Debug
    var_dump($ret);
    var_dump($output);
    var_dump($error);
?>
```

when i use this: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Exact Software\bin\E5Shell.exe" in cmd it does work and it starts the program.

I tried a lot but it just don't seem to work for me.

Comment: escape your backslashes or trying forward slashes might help. Also I've never seen double quotes inside single quotes for an exec.

Comment: `$ret = exec('C:/Program Files (x86)/Exact Software/bin/E5Shell.exe', $output, $error);` try that

Comment: Will PHP do that? Does this present a security threat?

Comment: nope those options don't work

Comment: PHP runs on the server and can only start a program on the server. This won't work. The best you can do is to provide a link to your program's custom URL, if it has one. This is how `mailto:` works.

Comment: I now have the application on my webserver but it still doesn't work